# Why datetime picker behaves?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5

I have model:

```
const string MyDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = MyDateFormat, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

and view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
```

who for some reason don't set model value when the form load, I wonder why?
I have to manually:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var elem = $("#Date").val('@Model.Date.ToString(MyDateFormat)');
    });
</script>
```

But, in the form i see dd.MM.yyyy (it's my computer locale) format, why?
[image]

If trying set MyDateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy", not work, see dd.MM.yyyy:
[image]

I understand, that yyyy-MM-dd is .net runtime local format, and dd.MM.yyyy is my computer local format.
How to do so as not to depend of the locale of the computer and .net runtime locale?

Comment: What datepicker are you using? jQuery UI?

Comment: Bootstrap datepicker use

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't ship with a datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your missing the curly braces around the expression.

Try wrapping the expression `yyyy-MM-dd` in curly braces like this `{0:yyyy-MM-dd}`

```
const string MyDateFormat = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}";

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = MyDateFormat, ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

You could also use the following in your view, instead of decorating your model property with the `DisplayFormat` attribute.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class="datePicker"});
```

Comment: thanks, with TextBoxFor works, but textbox style not applied, added class "form-control" -  displayed without style

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you specify `DataFormatString` wrong, because instead of `"yyyy-MM-dd"`you should use `"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"`. Please try the following code, it should work:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Date{ get; set; }
```